# Capturing Screenshot on failure in custom test library

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm currently using ROBOT for some automated testing, except I've run into a problem.
Anything that fails in the .robot file using a SeleniumLibrary keyword accurately captures screenshots as expected.

Unfortunately, I have some custom libraries alongside the SeleniumLibrary which I would like to do the same thing, but it does not. So if I call a keyword from my CustomLibrary1 for example, and it fails doing a 
`self.selib.wait_until_page_contains("Hello")`
then it will simply fail the test without capturing a screenshot.

The only workarounds I have been able to find so far are:

1. Throwing each and every keywords body into a `try` and using

`except:
    self.selib.capture_page_screenshot()` (not ideal as I have hundreds of keywords).

2. Adding a Test Teardown to every test I have, and using

`Run Keyword If Test Failed    Capture Test Screenshot`, which is also not ideal since, if the test fails while running a SeleniumLibrary keyword in the .robot file, then two screenshots will be captured and I have some hybrid data driven/keyword driven tests which do not call the test teardown between tests and only at the end of all the tests.

Is there a way to register a "run_on_failure" feature into custom libraries?

Comment: You could try to create a listener that will check that will run at the end of every keyword and if the keyword is from your library and failed than handle it. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have hundreds of keyword the `try` block is the best way to do that.

Maybe you could manage it like so:

```py
keywords = ['Hello', 'World'] # etc.

# Include the try block in a function.
def try_keyword(keyword):
    try:
        self.selib.wait_until_page_contains(keyword)
    except:
        self.selib.capture_page_screenshot()
    # Eventually do_something_else()

# Pass a function as an argument
def try_function_and_keyword(function, keyword):
    try:
        function(keyword)
    except:
        self.selib.capture_page_screenshot()
    # Eventually do_something_else()

for keyword in keywords:
    try_keyword(keyword)
    try_function_and_keyword(driver.find_element_by_id, keyword)
```

I assume that possible exceptions involve your script.

If so, perhaps, using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module may be useful.
Or, even if possible exceptions involve the site, you may need request or response data. You can give a look to [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy), a really useful module.